# How to convert a protobuf message into Avro?

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, avro, kafka-producer-api, protobuf-java

I am attempting to convert a protobuf message into an Avro record in order to send it to a Kafka topic using KafkaProducer. I am aware there is a KafkaProtbufSerializer for the value.serializer, but I would like to convert the protobuf message into Avro to use the KafkaAvroSerializer. How would I do this?

Comment: Attempting how? Please show your code and errors you are getting

Comment: @OneCricketeer I haven't attempted exactly yet. I was hoping to see if there were examples of this being done online before.

Comment: There are examples for Proto consumer and Avro producers, separately, in Confluent documentation... Put them together on your own

Answer (score 0):

Use KafkaProtobuf**Deserializer** from a consumer with value.**de**serializer, then construct a new POJO to be used with KafkaAvro**Serializer** for a producer.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: What specific issues are you running into? The code is very simple if you already have a Protobuf consumer or Avro producer... `poll records ... FooProto p = record.value(); FooAvro a = new FooAvro(); a.setBar(p.getBar()); producer.send("avro", a);` ...

Comment: I don't have a Proto consumer. I have the Protobuf message itself and the Java generated Protobuf class code. I want to be able to send this to a KafkaProducer but using an AvroSerializer as the value.serializer

Comment: Okay, so remove the `poll` and `record.value()` part of the code I provided. There is no automatic way to convert Proto to Avro. You need to construct a brand new Avro-class object and set its fields. But at that point, there is not real value in generating proto classes when you can just do the same from an Avro schema - https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/getting-started-java/

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to try something like this. If you've got both the Protobuf schema and the equivalent Avro schema, and code generated from both in a language that supports reflection, you can use that to auto-transcribe fields from a GPB object into and Avro object.

The field names and structure need to match (or closely match in some predictable way, e.g. upper or lower case).

The idea is that you have a function that loops through every field in the GPB object, and uses the field name / path to also point to the equivalent field in the Avro object, and makes an assignment:

```
// Psuedocode
foreach (ValueMember gpbObjField in gpbObj)
{
    avroObj.FieldByName(gpbObjField.Name).Value = gpbObjField.Value
}
```

And have it recursively calls itself for non-primitive types (e.g. nested messages). Or something like that. I've done something similar in C#.

The benefit of getting this right is that you're then proof against changes in schema, which could be handy. Otherwise, if you have hand written code doing objA.Field = objB.Field for the whole object, it's a pain to maintain.

Comment: In Java classes, fields are private, so need to use setter functions, but yes, reflection can be one option. Though, I don't think `FieldByName` or `.Value` is a valid function / property

Comment: @OneCricketeer, it is very pseudo code indeed (i.e. if it is valid Java, that's by random luck).